# Getting object reference error when Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint is used

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am getting error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object SinglePoint.Update () (at Assets/Script/SinglePoint.cs:52)

and this is my block of code

```
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

        //line 52 where error exists: Vector3 
        currentPosition=Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        currentPosition.z=-5.0f;

        InstatiateCirclePoint(currentPosition,currentLineRenderer.transform);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed the correct line of code, you should confirm that you have a Camera added to your scene and that it has the Tag "MainCamera" attached to it.

[image]